# How to implement drag and drop with nested lists in angular using angular cdk?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to build Trello like application using angular. User should be able to drag and drop items between lists and also within the same list and reorder lists. I'm using CDK drag and drop for this. I'm able to drag and drop items within the same list, but not able to drag and drop items between lists or reorder. I'm completely stuck on this. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is `kanban.component.ts:`

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-kanban',
  templateUrl: './kanban.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./kanban.component.scss'],
})
export class KanbanComponent {
  data = mockData;

  onDrop(event: CdkDragDrop<any[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }

  onCardDrop(event: CdkDragDrop<any[]>, cards: any[]) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(cards, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      const movedCard = cards[event.previousIndex];
      transferArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Here is `kanban.component.html:`

```js
<div class="kanban-board">
  <div class="kanban-columns" cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="data" (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop($event)">
    <div class="kanban-column" *ngFor="let column of data" cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="column">
      <h2>{{ column.category_title }}</h2>
      <div class="kanban-cards" cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="column.tasks"
        (cdkDropListDropped)="onCardDrop($event, column.tasks)">
        <div class="kanban-card" *ngFor="let card of column.tasks" cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="card">
          {{ card.item_title }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is `sample of data:`

```js
interface ICategory {
  id: string;
  order_id: string;
  title: string;
  tasks: {
    id: string;
    order_id: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
  }[];
}
```